# For Iteration on int array

Tags: java

I've been experimenting with `for` on array and was trying to do use the array iteration. Why aren't those 2 codes doing the exact same thing? The first one works perfectly, the second one was my attempt to make it look cleaner.

```
/**
 * resetSelectionOn
 * 
 * Module permettant de reinitiliser la selection d'une case et de supprimer
 * le groupe dont elle fait partie
 * 
 * @param emplacement
 */
public void resetSelectionOn(int emplacement) {

    int group = groupID[emplacement];

    for (int i = 0; i < groupID.length; i++) {
        if (groupID[i] == group) {
            groupID[i] = 99;
            selected[i] = false;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < groupID.length; i++) {
        if (groupID[i] > group) {
            groupID[i]--;
        }
    }

    **// This is the one that isn't working and is suppose to do the exact same thing as the one right over**
    for ( int i : groupID) {
        if(i > group)
            i--;
    }*/

    listeGroupCree.remove(group);

    selected[emplacement] = false;
    nbGroupCree--;
}
```

Anybody can explain me the difference between the 2 codes? Thanks!

group is a tab that contains the number of the group that a number is in. Example : I have 6 digits randomly generated. Let's say [1][2][3][4][5][6] groupID is an ArrayList that tells me in witch group this number is curently used. For example, if 2 and 3 were creating the number 23 by being part of the same group(let's say 2) This code is my code to reset the selection of said group. That group refers to the position it is in the ListeGroupCree. If 23 is group number 2, then ListeGroupCree[2] would return 23

Comment: You reference `group`. What is that?

Comment: You can't modify the array value from an `int` primitive. It's not a reference type.

Comment: It's for the exact same reason that that `int i = groupID[10]; --i;` only changes the value of `i`, not what's at index 10 in the `groupID` array.

Comment: @Sub6Resources it's a tab that contains the number of the group that a number is in.

Example : I have 6 digits randomly generated. Let's say [1][2][3][4][5][6]

groupID is an ArrayList<integer> that tells me in witch group this number is curently used. For example, if 2 and 3 were creating the number 23 by being part of the same group(let's say 2)

This code is my code to reset the selection of said group. That group refers to the position it is in the ListeGroupCree. If 23 is group number 1, then ListeGroupCree[1] would return 23

Comment: @KevinAnderson Would there be a way do to it with that kind of FOR, or do I have to go the longer way?

Comment: Please consider [edit]ing your original post and including this information.

Comment: Nope.  If you want to alter the actual array elements, you have to use a regular `for` loop with an explicit index.  No great loss though: it's the same number of lines of code but slightly more typing on each line....

Answer (score 0):

Compare the two snippets:

```
for (int i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
    groups[i]--;
}
```

and

```
for (int g : groups) {
    g--;
}
```

The first segment will decrement every element of `groups`.  The second segment will do nothing at all.  This is because the second segment is equivalent to

```
for (int i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
    int g = groups[i];
    g--;
}
```

So you are getting a new variable, decrementing it and discarding the result.

Answer (score 0):

To add you can notice the same difference, as pointed by others, If you decompile the generated class file 
Notice the 1st decompile loop and 2nd one

One which works for you

```
        for(i = 0; i < this.groupID.length; ++i) {
            if(this.groupID[i] > group) {
                --this.groupID[i];
            }
        }
```

The one which isn't working for you

```
        int[] var7 = this.groupID;
        int var4 = var7.length;

        for(int var5 = 0; var5 < var4; ++var5) {
            int i = var7[var5];
            if(i > group) {
                --i;
            }
        }
```

If you notice, 1st one is working on array reference.
2nd one is just modifying the primitive value.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i: array) {
    i++;
}
```

In the above example the `i` is a local copy of one of the values in the array. It is only valid for the single iteration. You are essentially changing the value of a copy.